# H.264 over RTP - Identify SPS and PPS Frames

Tags: c++, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I have a raw H.264 Stream from an IP Camera packed in RTP frames. I want to get raw H.264 data into a file so I can convert it with `ffmpeg`.

So when I want to write the data into my raw H.264 file I found out it has to look like this:

```
00 00 01 [SPS] 
00 00 01 [PPS]
00 00 01 [NALByte]
[PAYLOAD RTP Frame 1]     // Payload always without the first 2 Bytes -> NAL
[PAYLOAD RTP Frame 2]
[... until PAYLOAD Frame with Mark Bit received]  // From here its a new Video Frame
00 00 01 [NAL BYTE]
[PAYLOAD RTP Frame 1]
....
```

So I get the `SPS` and the `PPS` from the `Session Description Protocol` out of my preceding `RTSP` communication. Additionally the camera sends the `SPS` and the `PPS`in two single messages before starting with the video stream itself.

So I capture the messages in this order:

```
1. Preceding RTSP Communication here ( including SDP with SPS and PPS )
2. RTP Frame with Payload: 67 42 80 28 DA 01 40 16 C4    // This is the SPS 
3. RTP Frame with Payload: 68 CE 3C 80                   // This is the PPS
4. RTP Frame with Payload: ...  // Video Data
```

Then there come some Frames with Payload and at some point a RTP Frame with the `Marker Bit = 1`. This means ( if I got it right) that I have a complete video frame. Afer this I write the Prefix Sequence ( `00 00 01` ) and the `NAL`from the payload again and go on with the same procedure.

Now my camera sends me after every 8 complete Video Frames the `SPS` and the `PPS` again. ( Again in two RTP Frames, as seen in the example above ). I know that especially the `PPS` can change in between streaming but that's not the problem.

My questions are now:

**1. Do I need to write the SPS/PPS every 8th Video Frame?**

If my `SPS` and my `PPS` don't change it should be enough to have them written at the very beginning of my file and nothing more?

**2. How to distinguish between SPS/PPS and normal RTP Frames?**

In my C++ Code which parses the transmitted data I need make a difference between the RTP Frames with normal Payload an the ones carrying the `SPS/PPS`. How can I distinguish them? Okay the `SPS/PPS` frames are usually way smaller, but that's not a save call to rely on. Because if I ignore them I need to know which data I can throw away, or if I need to write them I need to put the `00 00 01` Prefix in front of them. ? Or is it a fixed rule that they occur every 8th Video Frame?

Comment: Thanks for this question. I have the same question as you. I read through live555 source code and do not know why they save each packet/frame like that. After reading this thread, things become clear to me. As a suggestion based on live555 implementation, the marker bit is only used in other codec, H264 has its own start_bit and end_bit to represent for start/end of frame, marker bit is not used for H264.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. If the SPS and PPS do not change, you could omit them except the 1st ones.
2. You need to parse the nal_unit_type field of each NAL, for SPS, nal_unit_type==7; for PPS, nal_unit_type==8.

As I remember, nal_unit_type is the lower 5 bits of the 1st byte of a frame.

```
nal_unit_type = frame[0] & 0x1f;
```

Comment: This would mean that the first 2 Bytes of the `SPS` and the `PPS` frame are also some kind of "NAL Status" just like the first two bytes of every other RTP Frame? Or in other words - the nal_unit_type field where I expect 7 or 8 for the SPS and PPS is the same field wheere I expect 28 which means its video data?

Comment: For detailed definition of nal_unit_type, you may reference the H.264 document. btw, (payload[0] & 0x1f) == 28 means this is a fragmented video frame, in this situation, the actual nal_unit_type should be (payload[1] & 0x1f). This is defined in RFC3984.

Comment: Yeah I just read it and got it...but how do you know that the nal_unit_type = 28 is fragmented video frame? The RFC 3984 refers to http://www-ee.uta.edu/dip/courses/ee5356/H264systems.pdf Table 7.1 ( Page 63 ) - there the code 28 would fall under "Unspecified" .. ?

Comment: In table 1 of RFC 3984: 28     FU-A      Fragmentation unit                 5.8

Comment: Ah yeah of course - I got a bit confused since I need to look the code for the first 23 Values in that external paper ( link above ) and the other codes are in a table in the RFC. Well thank you that did it for me!

Answer (score 13):

1. You should write SPS and PPS at the start of stream, and only when they change in the middle of stream.
2. SPS and PPS frames are packed in a STAP NAL unit (generally STAP-A) with NAL type 24 (STAP-A) or 25 (STAP-B) STAP format is described in [RFC-3984 section 5.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984#section-5.7)
3. Don't rely on marker bit, use start bit and end bit in NAL header.
4. For fragmented video frames you should regenerate NAL unit using 3 NAL unit bits of first fragment (F, NRI) combined with 5 NAL type bits of first byte in payload (only for packets with start bit set to 1) check [RFC-3984 section 5.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984#section-5.8):

   > The NAL unit type octet of the fragmented
   > NAL unit is not included as such in the fragmentation unit payload,
   > but rather the information of the NAL unit type octet of the
   > fragmented NAL unit is conveyed in F and NRI fields of the FU
   > indicator octet of the fragmentation unit and in the type field of
   > the FU header.

**EDIT:** more explanation about NAL unit construction for fragmentation units:

this is first two bytes of a FU-A payload (right after rtp header):

```
|  FU indicator |   FU header   |
+---------------+---------------+
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|F|NRI|  Type   |S|E|R|  Type   |
+---------------+---------------+
```

to construct the NAL unit you should take "Type" from "FU Header" and "F" and "NRI" from "FU indicator"

[here](https://github.com/hawell/rcpplus/blob/master/src/rtp.c) is a simple implementation

Comment: Can you explain item 4? I've read that section of the spec and the blurb you quoted several times and I don't understand what it is describing.  Does it mean that the FU indicator should be reconstructed based on these rules, and the FU header discarded, and the first 5 bits of the payload discarded, and the now reconstructed FU indicator be concatenated with the payload (less the first 5 bits)?  Thank you

Comment: @Joshua: I added some more explanation

Comment: Thank you, the code example is very elegant, and I appreciate your simplified explanation.  In hindsight the blurb you quoted is straightforward, but your explanation in item 4 suggests using bits from the payload, hence my confusion.  I understand now what you mean though.